# How to remove bottom overlay ads from custom Youtube player Android

Tags: android, ads, android-youtube-api

I am developing a video application on Android that plays videos from YouTube. For this purpose, I am using YouTube Android API. I have made my player to CHROMELESS as follows:

```
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
            boolean wasRestored) {
         player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
         player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
            }
```

Everything is working fine but while video playing bottom overlay ads are coming at the bottom.
 How can I hide or remove that bottom overlay ads?
If it is not possible then how can I block touch event on that portion of ads only.

I don't want my users to leave my application.

Comment: Did u resolved it? How?

Comment: i didnt  got any solution, as we cant add any view on the top of that portions , as it will violates youtube terms and conditions

Answer (score 0):

set Change

```
  player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
         player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
```

To:---

```
 player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
```

**NOTE:-** Load the video first then set your player style may be helpful to you

Comment: no we cant do that ,we have to first set playerStyle then Load video."CHROMELESS"  playerStyle is for removing default controls from player so that developer can build their own controls for pause ,stop etc.